# Java - Updating / Changing serialized classes

Tags: java, serialization, save, load, updating

I am creating a program for a small business. This program is meant to have smaller modules that, when developed, will be attatched to the rest of the program. It contains an "Article" and a "Category" class, which is contained in lists in a "ArticleDatabase" class. 
This class is serialized and saved to a file to the harddrive. 
The Register module is complete, and the "Receipt" class, is likewise contained within lists in a "RegisterDatabase" class, which is serialized and saved to a separate file.
System settings, are saved in the same manner.

However, now i am designing a Invoice module, and found out that i need to add a field to the "Article" class, and to the System data.

The register is now being used, and contains actual data that needs to be saved, and therefore i can't just change the class, since this gives an InvalidClassException when i load.

Since i know that this will be a common problem in the future too, i need some advice on how to tackle this problem.

How can i setup a system i which i can save a file from a class, and load the data into an updated or new version of this class, or should i approach this in an entirely new way?

I have tried loading the data form the old file in to a duplicate class with the needed fields addded, but reconfiguring the program to use the new files instead is a very cumbersome task, and if i have to do this every now and again, a lot of time will be wasted doing this.

The methods used for saving loading are as follows:

```
 public void saveArticleDB() throws IOException {
        // Write to disk with FileOutputStream
        FileOutputStream f_out = new FileOutputStream("articles.data");

        // Write object with ObjectOutputStream
        ObjectOutputStream obj_out = new ObjectOutputStream(f_out);

        obj_out.writeObject(MyMain.articleDB);
    }

    public ArticleDB loadArticleDB() throws IOException {

        try {
            FileInputStream f_in = new FileInputStream("articles.data");
            ObjectInputStream obj_in = new ObjectInputStream(f_in);
            Object obj = obj_in.readObject();

            if (obj instanceof ArticleDB) {
                return (ArticleDB) obj;
            } else return null;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            new MessageDialog("Article DB - File not found");
            return null;
        } catch (InvalidClassException e) {
            new MessageDialog("Article DB - Class didnt match");
            return null;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            new MessageDialog("Article DB - Class not found");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The classes that delivers data to the save file, implements Serializable, and thats the only code used regarding the saving and loading of the class.

This is my first attempt with serializing, saving and loading, which means i am quite new to this, and therefore know/understand very few of the concepts regarding these subjects.

Advice is much appreciated :-)

Comment: If you want backwards compatibility, the default Java serialization is not the way to go.  A number of alternatives are out there, ranging from XML to JSON to GPB.  I'd suggest exploring these alternatives, and then come back with a question on your choice if necessary.

Comment: If you strongly need to use java serialization (which was designed for exchanging objects between multiple JVM instances via RPC, message queues etc., rather than for storage), then implement [`readObject()`, `writeObject()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) in your classes to make them some "version independent"

Comment: It doesn't have to be serializing. It was just the most common subject when i searched google for save/load. I just need something that can make a file that i can save/load on a regular harddrive, and somehow support that i can  load into an updated object.

Comment: If you just add a field to your class, and make sure to keep the same serialVersionUid as before, you will still be able to read older versions of the serialized class. Your new field will just have its default value. But serialization is an awful choice for long-term storage. Use JSON (or XML, but I much prefer JSON), so that even if you want to do a complete change of the model, you'll still be able to read the old files using the old format, and migrate it to the new format. Or just use a relational database, which allow executing SQL script to migrate the schema from one version to another